# Cursor for inserting in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write a cursor for inserting in ancestor table which takes data from employee details.

For example if employee has details like:

```
Empid supervisor
A      B
B      C
C      D
```

That means B is supervisor of A, C is supervisor B and D is supervisor of C. So we need to insert in ancestor table the whole hierarchy. For example:

```
Empid Supervisor Level
A      A         0
A      B         1
A      C          2
A      D         3
```

Can someone please advice how can I do that?

Comment: What database product? In MS SQL Server, this can be easily done with recursive CTE (Common Table Expression)s.   No need for a cursor at all.

Comment: Its Toad database

Comment: Toad is client database management utility, not a database. It is used for Oracle database only, right?

Comment: yes oracle database only

Comment: I'm not an Oracle expert, Is there an equivalent to MSSQL CTEs in Oracle, anyone?

Comment: sorry, I am not sure on this.

Comment: if we can get how your schema is laid out we can provide a better help. we can point you in the direction of a recursive cte, but we really need more info. please provide the schema, and if you already have a query you have tried can you please provide that as well.

Comment: FYI, Quest calls all of their DB development products TOAD, for instance TOAD for SQL Server. They share the same name, but not the same interface. IMHO, don't mess with the non-Oracle products without trying first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select connect_by_root empid as empid, supervisor, level
from t
connect by empid = prior supervisor
union
select empid, empid, 0
from t
;
```

output will come as

```
A   A   0
A   B   1
A   C   2
A   D   3
B   B   0
B   C   1
B   D   2
C   C   0
C   D   1
```

Comment: Hello, actually I have not used connect_by_root earlier. Can you please give a simple description for this.

Comment: also, I wanted to insert in a table.

Comment: connect_by_root gives the start of the branch. Traversing the tree started a branch for each record in the table, and connect_by_root gives the starting point

Comment: If you want to inser, you just need to do: insert into t_expand (empid, supervisor, manage_level) select ..... (the same select above)